# Riot JS: Render posts based on date in reverse order javascript

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am using the below function for sorting based on date:

```
if(self.data.blogTopicsArr.length > 1) {
    console.log('sorting array by date');
    self.data.blogTopicsArr = self.data.blogTopicsArr.sort(function(a,b) { 
        return new Date(a.start).getTime() - new Date(b.start).getTime() 
    });
}
```

but able to render it in sorted order only on page refresh. but why I am not able to understand.

I am calling `this.update()` after sorting and on `update` I am rendering the view below:

```
<li each="{item , i in data.blogTopicsArr}">
    <blog_topic_title index={i} id={item.post_id} topic={item}></blog_topic_title>
</li>
```

How do I render the view with sorted array on calling `this.update()`??

Comment: where are you calling `this.update()`? I don't see it in your sort code, it could/should be right after.

Comment: .. and can you paste a live example of it not working? e.g. plnkr